# Passing email address as a route parameter is not working

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, url-parameters, asp.net-apicontroller

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 3.1 API

I want to pass in the user's email address as part of the url (query string), and have the API look up their password hash and return the email and the passhash to me in JSON.

My code works BUT, I get odd values for the email address. It is either encapsulated in "/" "" or the variable "email" is shown not the email address test@test.com.

I'm probably not writing the url correctly or it can't handle the @ and period in the email address?

`https://localhost:5001/api/User/test@test.com`

does not work.

`https://localhost:5001/api/User/"test@test.com"`

returns: {"email":" \ "test@test.com\ "","passhash":"12121212121212"}

I want "email": "test@test.com" no " \ " before or after

`https://localhost:5001/api/User/email?email=test@test.com`

returns: {"email":"email","passhash":"12121212121212"}

I want "email": "test@test.com" not "email": "email"

My UserController:

```cs
[HttpGet("{email}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string email)
{
    email = email.ToString();
    IUsers user = new Users();
    IDictionary<string, string> fetch = await Task.Run(() => user.FetchUser(email));
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Fetch User - " + fetch);

    if (fetch["passhash"] != null)
    {
        // send back the user's email and passhash only if passhash isn't null
        return Ok(fetch);
    }
    else
    {
        // if passhash is null, send back a bad request HTTP 400.
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

The FetchUser method that access the database:

```cs
IDictionary<string, string> IUsers.FetchUser(string email)
{
    using (dbConnection)
    {
        //SQL Command
        string cmd = String.Format(@"select u.passhash from users u where email={0}", email);

        // Save results to result.
        string passhash = dbConnection.Query<string>(cmd).FirstOrDefault();

        IDictionary<string, string> fetchedUser = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        if (passhash != null)
        {
           // Add the result to the Dictionary
           fetchedUser.Add( "email", email);
           fetchedUser.Add("passhash", passhash);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("User {0} passhash was fetched", email);
        }
        else
        {
            // Add null result to the Dictionary
            // I'll use this to signal that there was no match.
            fetchedUser.Add("email", email);
            fetchedUser.Add("passhash", null);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("User {0} provided incorrect passhash", email);
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);

        return fetchedUser;
    }
}
```

Any advice is appreciated :)

FYI:

I'm hashing the user's password and storing it in the database so I only need to send the hash rather than the password. The user's provided password will be hashed and if they both match then they're good.

I intend to [authorize] with JWT tokens before access to the API and use https connections to make sending the email and passhash more secure.

Comment: _"I'm hashing the user's password and storing it in the database so I only need to send the hash rather than the password"_ - and so the hash becomes the password. What problem does this solve, exactly? Also, you have a gaping SQL injection vulnerability, and your problem is caused by missing quotes in your SQL. Use parameterized queries instead, or rather, **don't roll your own authentication if you don't know what you're doing**.

Comment: What exactly happens when you use `https://localhost:5001/api/User/test@test.com`? Its working for me. "_does not work_" - is a very vague description for an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
string cmd = String.Format(@"select u.passhash from users u where email={0}", email);
```

to:

```
string cmd = String.Format(@"select u.passhash from users u where email='{0}'", email);
```

It might solve your current problem but:

STOP joining the parameters into the query string! This will lead to sql injection.

Use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got it working using parameterized queries as you recommended.  ```string cmd = String.Format(@"select u.passhash from users u where email = @Email");

 string passhash = dbConnection.Query<string>(cmd, new {Email = email }).FirstOrDefault();```

Comment: Now it works with this url: https://localhost:5001/api/User/test@test.com

Answer (score 0):

you can use this url:

```
https://localhost:5001/api/User/"test@test.com"
```

but fix your action:

```
[HttpGet("{email}")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string email)
 {
var email = email.Trim('"');
....your code
```

It should be working properly , but if you still have some problems try:

`````
[HttpGet("{email}")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string email)
 {
var email = email.Trim('"');

string cmd = String.Format(@"select u.passhash from users u where email='{0}'", email);

....your code

````
`````

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it did work, but using parametrized SQL query worked best